# Does mongodb master node need to be accessible from clients?

Tags: mongodb, replication, master-slave

In a MongoDB replica set, Does master node need to be accessible from clients? Or secondary nodes will redirect write queries to master node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your nodes must be accessible from clients. That way, if the primary goes down and a secondary is promoted to primary, your application will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary nodes will not proxy write requests to the primary node. To perform writes you need to be directly connected to the master node.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers aren't 100% correct.

1) if you are in a sharded environment then the clients need to be able to communicate with the mongos process which then communicates with the PRIMARY nodes (and the config servers) there could be a scenario where the application servers and separated from the PRIMARY mongodb server in a replica set yet they where able to communicate with the mongos processes which was then able to communicate with the PRIMARY mongodb server.

2) Another user noted that "all your nodes must be accessible from clients" while generally true not always true, in a situation where you had a delayed secondary in a separate data center only members of the replica set need to be able to communicate with the delayed secondary; however the application servers never need to communicate with it.